# Why GitLab api Compare is different from git diff?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-api

When comparing two branches from GitLab repository, using [gitlab api](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#compare-branches-tags-or-commits):

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/compare?from=master&to=feature
```

I get different from `git diff --name-only <from> <to>` results - more files than expected. Seems like gitlab's compare returns files with old commits.

Can you help me to understand why this is happening, please?

Comment: Does it match if you try `master...feature` locally?

Comment: @Chris it doesn't unfortunately. I've tried that. GitLab's compare still returns more files.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the repository in question?

Comment: @Chris sorry it's a private repository. I'll try to recreate the problem with an example rep

Comment: Good idea. We won't be able to help much without more information; if you can provide a [mcve] we'll be much more likely to give you a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if this has been resolved.  I have the same observations, more or less, as MRed.

Comment: They added 'straight' option, maybe this can help
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#compare-branches-tags-or-commits